# how can I install rosbridge on ros electric?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Anyone who can help with the question above?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64775/how-can-i-install-rosbridge-on-ros-electric?/) by [agrirobot-George](https://answers.ros.org/users/3227/agrirobot-george/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer: You can't install rosbridge 2.0 on Electric.

rosbridge 2.0 uses the catkin build system, which was not introduced until ROS Groovy.

You can probably install rosbridge 1.0 on Electric, since it uses the rosbuild build system, but it's out of date and tends to be buggy.

As an aside, ROS Electric is no longer supported; I strongly suggest you upgrade to a newer version of ROS.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2